# How to prove the following integral inequality?

Tags: calculus, integral-inequality

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be differentiable function with $f(0)=0$ and $0\leqslant f(x)'\leqslant 1$. Then 
>   $$3\left(\int_0^1f(x)^2dx\right)^3\leqslant \int_0^1f(x)^8dx.$$

My attempt:

$0\leqslant f(x)'\leqslant 1$ implies $0\leqslant f(x)\leqslant x$. then $0\leqslant f(x)^2\leqslant xf(x)$ and $0\leqslant f(x)^2\leqslant x^2$.

$$0\leqslant \int_0^1f(x)^2\leqslant 1/3$$

But these inequality can't relate $f(x)^2$ and $f(x)^8$. Any idea?

Comment: Take $f(x) = a x$ with $a<1$. You have $(a^6)/9 < (a^8)/9$, which is not true.

Comment: @Quillo: pls turn your comment into an answer to remove this post from unanswered tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality does not seem to be true in general. Take $f(x)=ax$ with $a<1$: for this function we have that $0<f'<1$  and $f(0)=0$, so it is a legit function according to your requests. By using your inequality,  a direct calculation gives $(a^6)/9<(a^8)/9$, namely $1<a^2$. This is a contradiction since we assumed $a<1$.